# PDFTk works on local but not working on private server

Tags: php, pdf, ssh, pdftk

I have private server CentOS 6 and I have installed `pdftk` program to generate pdf files. When I connect with SSH client, I can run pdftk program successfully. But I couldn't in `php` with `exec()` function.

I have a very simple php file as shown below. This is only to test if pdftk is working or not. When I ran this file on my localhost with xampp, it generates the file but when I tried on my private server, not gives error and not generates the file. I am not expert and expecting any help from you. Thanks in advance.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
exec("pdftk form.pdf output private.pdf");
```

The error look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Error: Failed to open output file:
  [1] => collated.pdf [2] => No output created.)
```

Note: I have tried this code on putty ssh client and works perfectly.

Comment: Most probably SELinux is not setup to allow httpd server to run this binary (which makes sense). AVCs in audit log will confirm that to you.

Comment: So what can I do ? Can you advice me something ? What should I type to google to fix this issue. ? @Jakuje

Comment: Typing into google will not fix the issue. You either want to understand the issue so you should find out what is SELinux and as I already wrote, have a look into audit log what was rejected and why, troubleshoot it probably with `selinux-troubleshoot` or `audit2allow` tools (no general advice from here). Or just turn off SELinux, if you don't care about security (which will make it *magically* work).

Comment: @Jakuje I turned off selinux temporarily and reboot my server but still same problem. I think there is another problem. What do you think?

Comment: How did you turn the SELinux off?

Comment: @Jakuje nano /etc/selinux/config  SELINUX=enforcing to SELINUX=disabled

Comment: And what errors you get? If not on the webpage, in the log? And if you raise log level in the httpd configuration?

Comment: @Jakuje The error is:  
 Array ( [0] => Error: Failed to open output file: [1] => collated.pdf [2] => No output created. .

 same exec code on putty works fine.

Comment: And are you in the same directory as when running from PuTTY?

Comment: @Jakuje Yes. With cd command I reach to my site folder and execute command then output comes. In same directory, there is index php file that includes exec command as I mentioned on top, giving this error.

Comment: Make sure running `exec("pwd")` before running the `pdftk` from php.

Comment: @Jakuje Still same problem. I used like this;  exec("pwd");  exec("pdftk code is here");

Comment: But what is the output of the `pwd` -- it will print your working directory.

Comment: @Jakuje  Gives this:   /home/mysite/subdomain.mysite.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error is: Array ( [0] => Error: Failed to open output file: [1] => collated.pdf [2] => No output created. . same exec code on putty works fine.

The difference you can spot is in the user running the code. In case of PuTTY, you are logged in as a different user than the user who is running your script when accessed from web. Since you are creating a new file, the user needs a write access to the directory, where you are. This is generally a bad idea to allow to write that user to the directory, where your scripts are so it is a good idea to create a new directory (such as `export`), where the apache user will have access to write:

```
mkdir export
chown apache:apache export
chmod 755 export
```

and modify your script to write a file into that directory:

```
exec("pdftk form.pdf output export/private.pdf");
```

Comment: chmod apache:apache export gives error "chmod: invalid mode: `apache:apache'"

Comment: Sorry, obviously, there should be `chown` to make sure that this directory is owned by the `apache` user (I hope that it is the correct one on CentOS -- otherwise find out the right using `exec("id")` from your script).

Comment: Thanks for your helps but it still gives same error Array ( [0] => Error: Failed to open output file: [1] => export/private.pdf [2] => No output created. [3] => Error: unable to open file for output: export/private.pdf )

Comment: So once more check and verify what are the permissions of the `export` directory and if the file is not yet there with "bad permissions" using `ls -ldZ export export/private.pdf`.

Comment: Array ( [0] => uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody) )  id gives this.

Comment: So change the owner to `nobody`: `chmod nobody:apache export` for example.